# Chaining 32bit content length field to 8bit message in js socket

Tags: javascript, binary, marshalling, flatbuffers

I'm using Flatbuffers over sockets, which sends 8 bit binary buffers between NodeJS based client to GO based server.
In order to support to dynamic size messages, I've added as suggested from another stackoverflow thread
I've added a 32 bit size content prefix header to announce the size of the message to deal with dynamic size messages.

I'm unsure as to if I've made the best possible way to convert (except using bitwise operations) the 32 bit value to 8 bit array. I'd be happy for recommendations for optimizations or other solutions.

```
const serializedMessage = builder.asUint8Array(); //returns the constructed flatbuffer message in binary format ready to be sent
let result = new Uint8Array(4 + serializedMessage.length); //adding 4 bytes to accomdate the 32 bit size content length
let view = new DataView(result.buffer);
view.setUint32(0, serializedMessage.length, true);
result.set(serializedMessage, 4);
socket.write(Buffer.from(result.buffer));
```

Comment: I'm no JS expert, but this at least appears correct to me. The only unfortunate thing is that it involves a copy.